# Mocha tests take 20 seconds to get started in docker?

Tags: testing, docker, mocha.js, docker-compose

I'm testing frontend-only-code with mocha, docker-compose and node. The following is run in docker using `docker-compose run`.

```
NODE_ENV=test env NODE_PATH=$NODE_PATH:$PWD/src mocha $(find . -name 'test_*.js') --compilers js:babel-core/register -r jsdom-global/register --require babel-polyfill
```

It takes about 15-20 seconds until the **first (!)** test starts running.

I thought the docker container would boot fast because after 2 or 3 seconds my shell command (see above) is shown on the console. (Which I assumed, would mean the container is up). But after the command is shown it takes 15 - 20 seconds to run the first test.

What's wrong?

Edit: I'm on a Macbook Pro with macOS

Comment: OK, seems to be a Mac-only issue. The thing runs blazing fast on my Linux machine...

Comment: Hard code the test file names and see if that helps?

Comment: I assume its this: https://forums.docker.com/t/file-access-in-mounted-volumes-extremely-slow-cpu-bound/8076, so i will probably keep working on Linux... bad for docker which i actually chose for cross platform development....

Comment: Do read this also https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs/#performance-issues-solutions-and-roadmap

Comment: I see.. . .thank you for the reference!